# i cannot compare matching passwords client and database for login?

Tags: php, mysql

i use from below code for login.

```
$sid = trim($_POST["id"]);
$pcode = trim(md5($_POST["pcode"]));
include_once "../conf.php";
$pdo = connect();
$sql_log = "select * from `manager` where `sid` = $sid limit 1";
$do_log = $pdo->prepare($sql_log);
$do_log->execute();
$num_log = $do_log->rowCount();
if($do_log){
    if($num_log == 1){
        while($row_log = $do_log->fetch()){
            $pcode_db = $row_log["pcode"]; //md5 password
        }

            if(var_dump($pcode == $pcode_db)){ //or $pcode == $pcode_db, both return false
                return true;
            }else{
                return false; // i get false for any password}
        }
    }
}
```

i can not login to right password! i set md5 password in database manually with phpmyadmin

Comment: First have a read of this -> http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: whay are you using var_dump in if condition,can't you match them directly or var_dump for both variable as var_dump($pcode)==var_dump($pcode_db)

Comment: Does `md5($_POST["pcode"], true)` give anything?

Comment: idm>>> i check all the variable

Comment: How might two variables are not equal when those are equal in echo and in number of character!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this works, but it did. I set md5 password (do md5 with PHP) in my database manually with phpMyAdmin(insert)!

```
structure column pcode >>varchar(32)
```

The md5 password has 32 characters, but when it's set from insert in phpMyAdmin, the pcode column only contains 31 characters... So I used SQL in phpMyAdmin for setting the md5 password!

```
update `manager` set `pcode` = MD5("my password") where `sid` = 7283
```

and then it is completely set to 32 characters. Could someone explain why this happens?

Comment: This is what I said.  MySQL MD5 is not the same algoritham as PHP MD5. You need to use one or the other.  If you are using SQL and MD5 you will get a different result than using PHP and MD5.

Answer (score -1):

> i set md5 password in database manually with phpmyadmin

MySQL MD5 is not the same algoritham as PHP MD5.  You need to use one or the other.

Comment: You are using your PDO wrong and thus losing your sql injection protection that is built into PDO.  Read the documentation on parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Following code is just like your code but little change sql query.

```
$sid = trim($_POST["id"]);
$pcode = trim(md5($_POST["pcode"]));
include_once "../conf.php";
$pdo = connect();
$sql_log = "select * from `manager` where `sid` = $sid and `pcode` = $pcode";
$do_log = $pdo->prepare($sql_log);
$do_log->execute();

if($do_log){ // if incoming sid and pcod will match
   return true;
}else{
   return false; 
}
```

I don't know how to work of your connect() function. Another way to connect sql is like that:

```
 $sid = trim($_POST["id"]);
 $pcode = trim(md5($_POST["pcode"]));
 include_once "../conf.php";

 mysql_connect('server_name','user_name','password');
 mysql_select_db('DB_name');
 $query = mysql_query("select * from `manager` where `sid` = $sid and `pcode` =  $pcode");
 if(mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    return true;
 }else {
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: If id and pcode have the validate function, it doesn't matter.

Comment: col. sharapnel>>> i use from == (equal) for condition and type not necessary same as type for Identical (===)!

Comment: shariphwar >>>> this sql not return row! but >>select * from `manager` where `sid` = $sid limit 1<<< return one row! so `pcode`='$pcode' act same as $pcode == $pcode_db !

Comment: if this sql not return row, your pcode with md5 is not match with your pcode from database.Yes, pcode='$pcode' act same as $pcode== $pcode_db but I want to say you that's you can check data at once by sql query. OK, firstly.. you can add correct pcode of database. If you not, you will check your md5 function at php and phpmyadmin.

Comment: So.. you should add new data(ip and pcode) to your database with your form (not manually with phpmyadmin) and try again to login with these new data.If you will... md5 function is different between php and phpmyadmin.